# Remove unwanted tags using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove `<p>` tags from my string having spaces or blanks or `<br />` inside. I tried this one

```
$html = "abc<p>&nbsp;</p><p></p><p> </p><p><br /></p><p>dd</p><b>non-empty</b>"; 
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*>(&nbsp;|\s)<\\/p[^>]*>/"; 
//$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/"; use this pattern to remove any empty tag

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
```

This works fine. It's removing spaces only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems your tags were swallowed up, could you post them as code?

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;?)*</p>#', '', $html);
```

Comment: I am no good at regular expressions, but you can add these to make it 95%-space/tab/br proof. 95, because i might miss something ...

&#8194;
&#8195;
&#8201;
&ensp;
&emsp;
&thinsp;
&#160;
&nbsp;
&#09;
  <-Tab
<br/>
\s

Answer (score 0):

You must build your regex carefully... Here is a solution:

- first build a regex which matches `<br />` with any number of spaces or `&nsbp;`:

`$special = "(?:<br\\s*/>|&nbsp;)";`

- then a regex which matches a space:

`$normal = "\\s";`

- then you use the classical `normal* ( special normal* ) *` pattern:

`$re = "<p\\s*>$normal*($special$normal*)*</p\\s*>";`

- This should yield the correct result, and it works with any combibation of spaces or br tags:

`echo preg_replace("$re", "", $html);`